# Don't let wsdl2java generate @XmlSeeAlso annotation

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I use Apache CFX wsdl2java tools to generate java code from a given WSDL. Details of how to use it can be found here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

All of my generated code has a large part that is shared among different wsdl's, for example the classes BaseRequest and BaseResponse from which all wsdl-specific requests and responses inherit. I would like to group the shared "base" classes in a common project. However, those base classes have an @XMLSeeAlso annotation that differs for each wsdl. For example:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({SessionRequest.class})
```

And another baseRequest class from another wsdl would have:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ItemRequest.class})
```

This annotation is useless because I will never use it. But it is preventing me from putting the base class in a common folder because I will get "class file not found" errors because the common project has no knowledge of the other project their specific subclasses. **I can manually** remove the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotations to make everything work, but I would rather have the tool that generates the code do it automatically for me. Is there one of the many options (see the link above) that does this? Another option would be a batch file script that strips those lines from the file automatically for me.

Comment: Did you put these common classes into their own XSD and under a specific namespace?

Comment: Yes, they are all part of unique namespace. I already put them in a separate java package.

Comment: Did you put BaseRequest and BaseResponse in separate XSD and are the other classes of type BaseRequest and BaseResponse? I would be nice to see a small example of the WSDL etc to try and help. Without that I am going to be guessing at best.

Comment: @Namphibian You can find an example of one of the wsdl's here: pastebin.com/K4U40Wgu. The elements loginrequest and loginresponse inherit the baseRequest and baseResponse.